# how to keep the dialogflow df-messenger's initial speech bubble closed all the time?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Just started using Dialogflow df-messenger and it opens a speech bubble automatically when the web site is loaded.

Could anyone show me how to keep the speech bubble closed for all the time?

Answer (score 0):

got an answer from the team.

The trick is adding the following attribute in df-messenger tag:
wait-open="true"